# Getting NULL POINTER With Dependency Injection in QuartzJobBean extended class

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

Iam using Quartz scheduler to run a Job, Here i am getting Null pointer Exception in the 
QuartzJobBean extended class at Autowired Object i.e at DailyEmailsJob {testService.ts();}

please find the code below

This is the scheduler Class, Here i am calling DailyEmailsJob class

```
 @Component
    public interface EmailSchedulers {

        void dailyEmailTrigger();

        @Service
        @Transactional
        @Slf4j
        public class Impl implements EmailSchedulers{

            @Override
            public void dailyEmailTrigger() {

            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(DailyEmailsJob.class)
                                        .withIdentity("DailyEmail", "group1")
                                        .build();

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                                            .withIdentity("DailyEmailTrigger", "group1")
                                            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 3 * * ?"))   //At 03:00:00am every day
                                            .build();

            //schedule it
            Scheduler scheduler;
            try {
                scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.info("erorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
            }

            }
    }
```

QuartzJobBean  EXTENDED CLASS, Here at testService.ts(); i am getting Null pointer as shown in Error.

```
 @Slf4j
 @Component
 public class DailyEmailsJob extends QuartzJobBean {

        @Autowired
        private TestService testService;    

            @Override
        protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
            log.info("**************** DAILY SCHEDULER STARTED*****************");
            testService.ts(); // Getting null pointer
            log.info("**************** DAILY SCHEDULER ENDEND*****************");
        }   
    }
```

This is the service class I am injecting at DailyEmailsJob  class

```
@Component
    public interface TestService {

        void ts();

        @Slf4j
        @Service
        public class Impl implements TestService{

            @Override
            public void ts() {
                 log.info("SERVICE WORKED");
            }
            }
    }
```

### This is the Error:

```
2018-09-23 03:00:00.040  INFO 6020 --- [eduler_Worker-1] DailyEmailsJob         : **************** DAILY SCHEDULER STARTED*****************
2018-09-23 03:00:00.041 ERROR 6020 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell              : Job group1.DailyEmail threw an unhandled Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at DailyEmailsJob.executeInternal(DailyEmailsJob.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]

2018-09-23 03:00:00.042 ERROR 6020 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger              : Job (group1.DailyEmail threw an exception.

org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at DailyEmailsJob.executeInternal(DailyEmailsJob.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75) ~[spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the start of the `executeInternal` method in `DailyEmailsJob` class:

```
@Override
public void executeInternal(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    // Adding this autowires everything as needed
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);    
    ...
}
```